# Adding "search" while keeping pagination and sorting?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I wanted to add the "search" functionality to my model, but the `[querystring][1]` doesn't seem to work as I expected it to. Here's my attempt:

```
from django.db import models

class ProductsByOneDayMax(models.Model):
    product = models.TextField(max_length=65535, verbose_name="Product name")
    max = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Max daily IPs")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'precomputed_product_distinct_ip_one_day_max'

from django.db import connection as conn
from django.shortcuts import render
from viewer.models import ProductsByOneDayMax
import django_tables2 as tables

def list_products(request):
    class ProductsByOneDayMaxTable(tables.Table):
        class Meta:
            model = ProductsByOneDayMax
            exclude = ('id', )
    search = request.GET.get('search', '')
    objects = ProductsByOneDayMax.objects.filter(product__icontains=search)
    table = ProductsByOneDayMaxTable(objects)
    table.order_by = "-max"
    tables.RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, "plain_table.html", {'table': table,
                                                'title': 'Product list',
                                                'search': search})
```

And the view:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% querystring "search"=search %}
 <form class="form-inline" method="get" role="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
{% render_table table %}
{% endblock %}
```

Instead of adding the "search" field to the querystring, this only gets added to the output. What am I doing wrong?

In case it's relevant, I am using [bootstrap-tables2.css](https://gist.github.com/SonOfLilit/9600295).

Comment: I used [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) with a Django view. There are many plugins that integrates Django with Datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was solved in the last GitHub comment for the linked template:

> The bootstrap_pagination tag needs the full URL in order to properly
>   sort columns between pages:
>
> ```
> {% bootstrap_pagination table.page url=request.get_full_path %}
> ```
>
> This
>   assumes you have `"django.core.context_processors.request"` in
>   `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Modifying the template solved the problem.